# Is it possible to not build an app that'll fit Nexus ONE and Nexus S sizes in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using mainly Constraint layout. In Layout Resource files I created a regular, Large and XLarge XML files. Regular files consist of many phone sizes including Nexus ONE and Nexus S = 480 x 800 hdpi.

I understand using constraints but still when I make a xhdpi imageButton and use it for "normal" size phones and constraint it, I have to make the image extra small to fit Nexus ONE and Nexus S phones. But now that image is extra small on larger size phones and it's an issue for me.

Can I just create an app ignoring 480 x 800 size phones and smaller? Then add in app description that my app works on phones sizes 720 x 1280 and up?

Is there a way to make it that my app won't work at all on any phones smaller than 720 x 1280 phones?

Sign Up button on Nexus ONE is fine size:

[image]

Now that same Sing up button on Nexus 6 looks too small:

[image]

Comment: can you create drawable-small, drawable-large, drawable-xlarge resource folders and then create the three corresponding sizes of the ImageButtons and put those images into those drawable folders?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [the `<supports-screens>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) in your AndroidManifest.xml. This will allow you to write something like:

```
<supports-screens
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="360"/>
```

It's important to think in terms of `dp` and not `px`. You mention wanting a 720x1280 phone; chances are very good that this is an xhdpi phone, and so 720x1280 pixels is really 360x640 dp.

Comment: I don't see how to place various image sizes all on 1 XML file. Can I just make my app not compatible with certain phone sizes? Nexus ONE and Nexus S are phone sizes from 2010.

Comment: @iBEK maybe i misunderstand your comment, but ... when the app is loaded the resources (drawables and layouts, etc) from only one configuration are loaded. so the system will take care of that for you. (sorry, if that doesn't address your statement.)

Comment: is it possible for me to add Nexus S and Nexus ONE phone sizes into the "Small" size Layout resource file instead of the "Small" size be considered Android Wear devices?

Comment: @iBEK one other thought here: if the sign-up button just contains the text "sign up" consider changing it to a button with text inside. maybe the ImageButton is causing more trouble than it is worth?

Comment: So if my sign up button = 259dp layout_width and 79dp layout_height on the Nexus 6 devices, why doesn't the system take care of it for Nexus ONE and Nexus S phones? Instead on those phones it's exactly the same size which makes the imageButton look HUGE compared to the screen size.

How would I make that imageButton a different size for Nexus ONE and Nexus S while leaving the 259dp and 79dp for Nexus 6?

Comment: @iBEK  Maybe this will be a useful answer: I created a ConstraintLayout with a regular text Button that is dynamically sized and positioned within 4 carefully defined guidelines. See answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to having ImageButtons with different sized images, you might try just using a plain button which is constrained to various guidelines within a ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This button stays between the guidelines, which are defined so that the button is 10% away from the bottom, the left and the right sides of the parent layout. The button's width is thus 10% of the total layout. This will expand and contract according to the phone screen size.

Notice that on the Button element, the layout_width and the layout_height are both intentionally set to 0dp. This tells android to calculate the size and placement of the button dynamically.

[image]